# How to I get the info from a dictionary that I got from JSON - Objective-C/IOS/xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am currently getting a dictionary with json info that I call json.

```
 NSDictionary* json=[NSJSONSerialization
                            JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                            options:kNilOptions
                            error:&error];
```

I am then getting the Journals part of it with this code:

```
NSDictionary *journalJSON = [json objectForKey:@"journals"];
```

Everything so far is turing out as expected. But if I do `NSLog(@"Journals: %@", journalJSON);` it returns this:

```
Journals: (
        {
        journalDate = "0000-00-00";
        journalName = Test;
        "users_userID" = 2;
    }
)
```

So how do I go about getting that info? I want to store each one in a variable such as: self.journals.journalName = journalName;
(I already have these variables named and working. Just need to know how to get the info from the Journals variable into it)

I'm pulling this info from a MYSQL database through php so there might actually be more than   one journal....and I'd want to loop through and save each one into the class.

Right now I don't have a loop really and am doing this...though it's not right but hopefully you get the idea of what I want to accomplish:

```
journal *thisJournal = [[journal alloc]init];    
            thisJournal.name = name;            
            thisJournal.date = @"12/25/1981";
            [self.journals addObject:thisJournal];
```

I hope this all makes sense. I know I am close to the right answer because I can see the data. Just not sure how to parse it at this point.

THanks in advance!
Rob

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, try this:

```
journal *thisJournal = [[journal alloc]init];

for(NSDictionary *journal in journalJSON) {
    thisJournal.name = [journal objectForKey: @"journalName"];      
    thisJournal.date = [journal objectForKey: @"journalDate"];
    [self.journals addObject:thisJournal]; 
    thisJournal = nil;
}
```

Comment: nope, journalJSON is no NSDictionary but an NSArray of dicts, look at the debug output

Comment: I LOVE YOU! Worked perfect. Don't know how I overlooked that. THanks so much!!

Comment: Awesome, if it answered your question, please be sure to "accept" the answer with the check mark! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a subclass ob NSObject named Journal (by convention, all ObjC classes start with a capital letter) and give it some properties (name, date, etc.), and then do a foreach on your deserialized JSON (which btw is no dictionary but an NSArray of NSDictionaries), get the values out of the current dictionary and create a new Journal object with them, then store that in some kind of mutable array or set again.

I am sorry if this sounds rude, but it seems that you have hardly any experience with ObjectiveC and Cocoa touch. I would suggest, that you do not try to learn it all by yourself, but watch the Stanford CS193p courses on iTunes U to get started. After watching the first couple of those lectures, you will have a good basic understanding of how you accomplish what, and can start diving into advanced stuff.